# rope-auto-import did not work

Tags: python, emacs, rope, ropemacs

```
virtualenv env
pip install -e git+https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs.git@v0.24-beta2#egg=Pymacs-dev
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/agr/rope#egg=rope-dev
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/agr/ropemacs#egg=ropemacs-trunk
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/agr/ropemode#egg=ropemode-trunk
cd env/src/pymacs
make install
```

add following to .emacs
    (setq virtual-env (getenv "VIRTUAL_ENV"))
    (setq load-path (append
                     (list (concat virtual-env "/src/pymacs" ))
                     load-path))

```
(if (not (equal virtual-env 'nil))
    (let ((foo 'bar))
      (require 'pymacs)
      (pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
      (setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport 't)
      (setq ropemacs-autoimport-modules '("os" "shutil"))
      ))
```

after that, i could get code complete, document, definition.

**However**, after input rmtree, and execute rope-auto-imoport, the "from shutil import rmtree" didn't come.

Instead, i got the Message "**Global name rmtree not found!**"

Help me!

I have tried the config.py and add the extension_modules and python_path.

Answer (score 1):

```
M-x rope-generate-autoimport-cache
```